# Closing workbook AND VBA file

Tags: vba, excel

I have built a small VBA script, but I am having trouble fully closing out the workbook. I can close the work book but have noticed that it still shows up in the VBA editor. I have seen other forms on placing a bit of code to close everything out but I can not get it to work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
Private Sub PNTXLXS_Click()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

RCD_PNT.Hide


 With Sheets("Clash List").UsedRange
      mr = .Rows.Count
      mc = .Columns.Count
     .Range(Cells(1, 26), Cells(mr,mc)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
 End With

 Workbooks.Add

 Application.Visible = True

With ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
End With

With Selection
    .WrapText = False
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .WrapText = True
End With


InitialName = Range("A1") & " - " & Format(Now(), "DDMMYY")

filesavename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, 
fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=filesavename

ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

I know this is is the location i need something to close the VBA file correct?

```
Application.CutCopyMode = False

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

[image]

Thanks

Mark

Comment: First of all use `Option Explicit`! What is `RCD_PNT`?

Comment: RCD_PNT is the name of the userform. After the button is clicked i am hiding it.

Comment: Could you provide the calling code of the userform?

Comment: I have a button in one of the sheets that is tied to a module. The code inside the module is " RCD_PNT.Show"

Answer (score 2):

Remove `Application.Visible = True`from your code and instead of `RCD_PNT.Hide` use `Me.Hide`

```
Private Sub PNTXLXS_Click()

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled

Me.Hide


 With Sheets("Clash List").UsedRange
      mr = .Rows.Count
      mc = .Columns.Count
     .Range(Cells(1, 26), Cells(mr,mc)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
 End With

 Workbooks.Add

' Application.Visible = True

With ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
    .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats
End With

With Selection
    .WrapText = False
    .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .WrapText = True
End With


InitialName = Range("A1") & " - " & Format(Now(), "DDMMYY")

filesavename = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=InitialName, 
fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")

Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

And it is certainly a good idea to read [Userform.show](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2017/10/25/userform1-show/)

And it is better way to show the userform like

```
Sub Show_RCDPNT()

Dim frm As New RCD_PNT

    frm.Show
    Unload frm

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the better way to write the code. Even after the modifications the workbook is still open in the VBA project tree once the files is closed.

Comment: Difficult to tell what the cuase might be. Google tells it might be caused by Com AddIns but that's just a wild guess.

Answer (score 1):

I see a Workbooks.Add command so a new Workbook is being opened: are you doing anything with it? You're using Sheets before that line so you've got one opened already and it's the ActiveWorkbook, not that new one. Then you make Excel visible, work with some ranges, and save a copy of the ActiveWorkbook. But since the Excel Application object still exists that new workbook is hanging out in the Workbooks collection, yes? Maybe that's what you're seeing?

Comment: I am still really new to VBA so the code might not be as clean or it has redundancies in it. I have a worksheet that has data on it. I do not want to give out this main file out, but rather a copy of the data only. I am filtering it based on specific parameters that i want. Once i have it filtered to the specific content, i am copying the visable cells only, and then i am opening a new workbook and copying that data to the new file. I then prompt the user to provide a file name/location. Then the workbook close, but the workbook is still open in the VBA project tree.

Comment: I only noticed that project were not being closed out of VBA even though the excel document was closed, because i got an error "out of memory". I updated my original post with a picture that shows the issues.

Answer (score 0):

In your Worksheet, under Data tab, click the Connections icon to see if you are still linked to the closed workbook. If so, you may have to add a line to break the link (using your filename). Something like `ActiveWorkbook.Connections("filename").Delete`

Comment: I was able to duplicate this problem by reloading the test file instead of closing the test file and reopening it. The ActiveWorkbook.Connections("filename").Delete method won't work in that situation. - Sorry